# Getting error after import 'Fields' from 'redux-form' in react-boilerplate project

Tags: javascript, redux-form

After installing redux-form in `react-boilerplate` project, I am getting the error below on client console.

While importing this like that `import { Field } from 'redux-form';`
when I removed that line, the error is gone

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined
    at eval (FormSection.js:59)
    at Object../node_modules/redux-form/es/FormSection.js (reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js:13438)
    at __webpack_require__ (reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js:21)
    at eval (createAll.js:16)
    at Object../node_modules/redux-form/es/createAll.js (reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js:13503)
    at __webpack_require__ (reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js:21)
    at eval (index.js:46)
    at Object../node_modules/redux-form/es/index.js (reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js:13737)
    at __webpack_require__ (reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js:21)
    at eval (index.js from dll-reference reactBoilerplateDeps?dfc9:1)`

Comment: Did you run `npm run setup`? If so, try running `npm cache clean` first and `npm run setup` again

Comment: I think that implementing prop-types should fix your issue. 

   `npm install --save prop-types`

Comment: @Dario, thanks for helping, i followed your's suggestions but still getting same error

Comment: @Sergio, thanks for helping, i followed your's suggestions i have installed `prop-types` package but still getting same error.

Comment: you should add the code from "FormSection.js:59", a variable there with the property name string is not defined.